# Nodemailer working on localhost, but not on web host, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, smtp, localhost, host, nodemailer

I have been using nodemailer to send emails from my node js app, it used to work perfectly on localhost and it still does. I deployed the server to my online host, it didn't work giving me this error

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.253.112.108:465
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1174:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNECTION',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '172.253.112.108',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN' }
```

I have tried to look for solutions (XOauth2, using older version of nodemailer, setting environment variables) but none are working! what should i do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the config below:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  name: mydomain.com,
  pool: true,
  host: mydomain.com,  //as recommended by my host provider
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: info@mydomain.com,
    pass: MAILER_PASSWORD,
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});
```

The problem was with accessing the port 465 on the host.
changed my config to following solved the problem:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  name: mydomain.com,
  pool: true,
  host: mail.mydomain.com, //<----change
  port: 587,               //<----change
  secure: false,           //<----change
  auth: {
    user: info@mydomain.com,
    pass: MAILER_PASSWORD,
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});
```